Prove that : $\rho(x,y)= \sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+4(x_2-y_2)^2} $ is a metric

let $X= R^2$. If $x$ and $y$ are points in the plane and their cordinates are $x=(x_1,x_2), y=(y_1,y_2)$ prove that the given function is a metric.
I am currently stuck on proving the triangular difference, any idea on how to prove it ?

That one is done via the Minskowski inequality: It is as follows: $\sqrt{A^2+B^2} +\sqrt{C^2+D^2} \ge \sqrt{(A+C)^2+(B+D)^2}$. Apply this inequality for $A = x_1-y_1, B = 2(x_2-y_2), C = y_1-z_1, D = 2(y_2-z_2)$. You can verify the Minskowski inequality by squaring and complete square both sides and you get a square $\ge 0$.

One does not need the Minkowski inequality. Denote by $d$ the normal metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then note that
$$\rho((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2))= d((x_1,2x_2),(y_1,2y_2)) $$
Now denote by
\begin{align}
f:\mathbb{R}^2&\to \mathbb{R}^2 \\
(x_1,x_2)&\mapsto (x_1,2x_2)
\end{align}
Now we prove the triangle inequality for $\rho$:
let $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y},\mathbf{z} \in\mathbb{R}^2$. Then since $d$ satisfies the triangle inequality, we have
$$d(f(\mathbf{x}),f(\mathbf{y}))\leq d(f(\mathbf{x}),f(\mathbf{z})) + d(f(\mathbf{z}),f(\mathbf{y})) $$
but
$$d(f(\mathbf{x}),f(\mathbf{y}))= \rho(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}) $$
so we get
$$ \rho(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}) \leq \rho(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{z}) + 
\rho(\mathbf{z},\mathbf{y}) $$
Note that this reasoning works for any $f$, however the resulting $\rho$ is a metric if and only if $f$ is injective, which this particular $f$ happened to be.
